# ¿Cómo obtener el titulo de la cancion con mayor duracion y tambien con menor duracion por cada genero de las canciones?[PostgreSQL]

Tags: sql, postgresql

El punto esta trabajado en PostgreSQL y lo que llevo desarrollado hasta ahora es:

```
SELECT idGénero AS Genero,
 MAX(duración)  mayorDuracion,
 MIN(duración) menorDuracionc,
 FROM Canciones
 GROUP BY idGénero
 ORDER BY Genero;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

todo esto se basa en la tabla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estas dos tablas estan unidas en PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No soy experto en SQL ni en PostgreSQL pero igual quisiera dar mi granito de arena..

En este tipo de problema se puede hacer uso de las [vistas](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/sql-createview.html). Un vista no es mas que una forma de representar los datos de una tabla real.

Podríamos crear una vista que muestre las canciones con mayor duración según su género, sin embargo, hay que tomar en cuenta que pueda haber mas de una canción con una misma duración máxima, por esa razón, se debe hacer uso de la cláusula `GROUP BY` + la función `string_agg`, de esta forma se agrupa las filas duplicadas en una sola y se concatena los campos de dichas filas:

```sql
CREATE VIEW vista_min_duración AS
select 
canc.idGénero, 
géneros.nombre as género, 
string_agg(cast(idCanción as text), ',' ORDER BY idCanción) as idCanción_min, 
string_agg(título, ',' ORDER BY título) as título_min,
duración as duración_min
from canciones as canc
INNER JOIN géneros ON géneros.idGénero = canc.idGénero
WHERE duración = (SELECT min(duración) from canciones WHERE canciones.idGénero = canc.idGénero)
GROUP BY canc.idGénero, géneros.nombre, duración
ORDER BY duración_min;
```

Algo así debería dar como resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así mismo podríamos crear otra vista que nos muestre las canciones con menor duración según su género:

```sql
CREATE VIEW vista_max_duración AS
select 
canc.idGénero, 
géneros.nombre as género, 
string_agg(cast(idCanción as text), ',' ORDER BY idCanción) as idCanción_max, 
string_agg(título, ',' ORDER BY título) as título_max,
duración as duración_max
from canciones as canc
INNER JOIN géneros ON géneros.idGénero = canc.idGénero
WHERE duración = (SELECT max(duración) from canciones WHERE canciones.idGénero = canc.idGénero)
GROUP BY canc.idGénero, géneros.nombre, duración
ORDER BY duración_max;
```

Resultado (es un ejemplo):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Teniendo estas dos vistas ya creadas, simplemente debemos combinar (con [INNER JOIN](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-inner-join/)) los resultados de ambas vistas para tener las canciones de mayor y menor duración en una misma tabla virtual:

```sql
select 
vmaxd.idGénero, 
vmaxd.género, 

vmaxd.título_max, 
vmaxd.duración_max, 
vmind.título_min, 
vmind.duración_min
from vista_max_duración vmaxd
inner join vista_min_duración vmind on vmind.idGénero = vmaxd.idGénero;
```

Como resultado deberíamos obtener algo parecido así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por supuesto, la declaración de arriba se la pueda incluir en una vista o procedimiento almacenado.

Answer (score 2):

Si ya tienes la consulta para obtener los máximos y mínimos de las duraciones en cada género, puedes usar ésta como una subconsulta para seleccionar aquellas canciones que coincidan con estos valores:

```
SELECT C.idGénero,
       C.titulo,
       C.duración,
       CASE WHEN C.duración = M.mayorDuracion THEN 'Mayor' ELSE 'Menor' END
       FROM Canciones C
       INNER JOIN (SELECT idGénero       AS Genero,
                          MAX(duración)  AS mayorDuracion,
                          MIN(duración)  AS menorDuracion
                          FROM Canciones
                          GROUP BY idGénero
           ) M
           ON C.idGénero = M.Genero
           AND (C.duración = mayorDuracion OR C.duración = M.menorDuracion)
```

Podrías eventualmente si quieres, mejorar el `CASE` para considerar el caso en que tuvieras un único tema por genero, en cuyo caso la duración podría ser mejor catalogada como `Mayor y Menor`  o  `Canción única por genéro`

Answer (score 2):

## Obtener los nombres de máximos y mínimos.

Existen varias maneras de hacerlo y la diferencia consisten en qué pasa cuando hay varios que tienen la mínima o la máxima duración. En esta solución (clásica que funciona en cualquier SQL de cualquier base) solo ponen uno (el alfabéticamente menor).

La solución consiste en tomar la consulta que hiciste como subconsulta y juntar los nombres usando el valor mínimo o máximo para quedarse con el mínimo nombre.

```sql
drop table if exists Canciones;

create table Canciones(
  id serial,
  idGénero integer,
  duración interval,
  nombre text
);

insert into canciones(idGénero, duración, nombre)
  values (1, '00:03:00', 'Nombre 11'),
         (1, '00:03:00', 'Nombre 12'),
         (1, '00:04:00', 'Nombre 13'),
         (1, '00:05:00', 'Nombre 14'),
         (2, '00:03:00', 'Nombre 2');

select Genero, mayorDuracion, min(larga.nombre), menorDuracion, min(corta.nombre)
  from 
    (SELECT idGénero AS Genero,
       MAX(duración)  mayorDuracion,
       MIN(duración) menorDuracion
      FROM Canciones
      GROUP BY idGénero
    ) minmax,
    Canciones corta, 
    Canciones larga
  where corta.duración = minmax.menorDuracion and corta.idGénero = minmax.Genero
    and larga.duración = minmax.mayorDuracion and larga.idGénero = minmax.Genero
  GROUP BY minmax.Genero, mayorDuracion, menorDuracion
  ORDER BY Genero;
```

## Obtener todos los nombres (cuando hay repetidos)

Para obtener todos los nombres en 'PostgreSQL' se puede reemplazar `min(nombre)` por `string_agg(distinct nombre, ', ')` que lo que hace es concatenar en el mismo campo todos los nombres.